# TextView Marquee not working in Android 4.0 (ISO) Widget

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, marquee, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I fixed the below issue. A simple change. Replaced `android:lines="1"` with `android:singleLine="true"`.

---

Currently my app is showing the text in the widget as Marquee. It is working as expected in all Android OS except for 4.0 version. I have tested in Emulator with API level 14 and text is not scrolling (Marquee). Below is the layout xml being used to show the text in Marquee effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
     android:duplicateParentState="true"
     android:textSize="20dp">
    <requestFocus android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add your solution below and mark it as accepted, otherwise you can delete your question.

Comment: I fixed the below issue. A simple change. Replaced android:lines="1" with android:singleLine="true".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For clarification.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/your_text">
    <requestFocus
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
</TextView>
```

Comment: This was tested in Android 2.2 and 4.1.2 and works perfectly Thanks!